# Attic Water Pipes Vibrating

Tags: plumbing, water

My wife and I got back from a trip and now our attic water pipes are vibrating loudly when a toilet is flushed/sink is run/shower running, etc. I figured it was air in the pipes and shut off the water main and let all water drain from every sink, spigot and shower in the house. I turned the water back on and slowly worked back to front shutting off all the sinks/showers/spigots. This fixed the issue for about 24 hours, but I just flushed the toilet and it started again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Key diagnostic to figure out if this is incoming water vs. outgoing sewer: Run some water *without* it draining out - e.g., a sink with the drain plugged. Then drain the water. If the noise happens when filling the sink, problem is water pipes. If the noise happens when draining the sink, problem is sewer pipes.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact tried this and nothing happened.  Seems to be happening more consistently when the shower is run or a hose spigot.

Comment: 2 questions:  did you turn off your water main when you went on your trip? do the loud pipes vibrate the whole time water's running, or is it a single sudden jolt and a few moments of aftershock?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common problem, it’s called water hammer and it’s caused by the closing of a valve against water pressure, I’m more inclined to think this is more the toilet than sink or shower etc, (you may notice it happens when the WC is nearly full), if so then the noise comes from unsecured pipework, two options:

1. Change valve, (this would solve the noise but not the problem)
2. Clip the pipes

Comment: It happens the most when the shower or hose spigot is running.  It's hit or miss with the sink and toilet.  Why would this issue start happening now?

Comment: Probably from pipe work thats become insecure, any valve can cause the problem, the shower may have a solonoid valve, any use of water can create water hammer even from equipment thats not operating, still recommend securing pipes.

Comment: it could start now because of a change in weather, this is the most wood-swollen time of the year in the norther hemi, which can pinch/stretch/squeeze/rub/tug pipes attached to wood, which they usually are.